# text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml-parsing

I am trying to insert xml file in database but i am getting this error text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input.

Here is the query:

```
INSERT [EMR].[tblTemplateForm]
 (FormXML)
 VALUES ( CAST('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><EMR>
  <CustomTextBox xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Text>0.0</Text>
    <Type>TextBox</Type>
    <Width>300</Width>
    <id>txt1</id>
    <Label>POG(LMP)</Label>
    <LabelWidth>200</LabelWidth>
    <labelFontStyle>normal</labelFontStyle>
    <labelFontWeight>normal</labelFontWeight>
    <labelFontColor>Black</labelFontColor>
    <CaptionOrientation>Horizontal</CaptionOrientation>
    <NewControl>false</NewControl>
    <NumericText>0</NumericText>
    <TextMode>Singleline</TextMode>
    <rows>0</rows>
    <columns>0</columns>
  </CustomTextBox><?xml version="1.0"?>
  <CustomNumericTextBox xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Type>NumericTxtBox</Type>
    <Width>500</Width>
    <id>numTxt1</id>
    <Label>numTxt1</Label>
    <LabelWidth>200</LabelWidth>
    <labelFontStyle>normal</labelFontStyle>
    <labelFontWeight>normal</labelFontWeight>
    <labelFontColor>Black</labelFontColor>
    <CaptionOrientation>Horizontal</CaptionOrientation>
    <NewControl>false</NewControl>
    <NumericText>3</NumericText>
  </CustomNumericTextBox><?xml version="1.0"?>
  <AllControlsCount xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Width>0</Width>
    <id>ControlsID</id>
    <LabelWidth>0</LabelWidth>
    <NewControl>false</NewControl>
    <NumericText>0</NumericText>
    <lblCount>0</lblCount>
    <txtCount>12</txtCount>
    <numTxtCount>1</numTxtCount>
    <ddlCount>0</ddlCount>
    <rbCount>0</rbCount>
    <cbCount>0</cbCount>
  </AllControlsCount>
</EMR>' as XML))
 GO
```

**Error message:**

```
Msg 9438, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 19, character 24, text/xmldecl not at the beginning of input
```

**Table structure:**

```
TABLE [EMR].[tblTemplateForm](
    [FormID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FormName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [FormDesc] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [FormXML] [xml] NULL,
    [Published] [bit] NULL,
    [FormType] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedID] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedID] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
```

Comment: Looks like what it says, line 19 of your xml you have an xml opening tag. Seems your xml parser does not like that, so I guess you will need to strip additional embedded xml open and close tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Repeating XML declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

If the XML declaration is included, it must be situated at the first position of the first line in the XML document

Comment: This worked for me.  IMHO, the parser should be a bit better and able to get by this, one gets a 'whale of an error' for such a tiny displacement....

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have extra

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

in two places? Remove them and it should work fine.

Raj